# Website consistently crashes Internet Explorer on my PC

Tags: internet-explorer, crash

I keep getting crashes when I load my site in IE, but I've no idea why. If I choose the option to restore the page then it will generally work, but the next link I click will crash IE.

How can I tell if this is something that lots of people are seeing, and how can I start tracking down the problem?

The site is http://www.freshholidays.com/

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by superuser question?

Comment: Where specifically is the crash? Can you share a .DMP file from the crashing process? Does it repro in No Add-ons mode?  http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/troubleshoot.asp#crash

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric, disabling Flash did the trick, so I've removed the only Flash component from the page (some clearspring.com tracking code used by an addthis.com button).

Comment: Eric: If you put the above as an answer then I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Also reported at http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6727

IE says I have Flash 6.0.88.0 installed, Firefox says 10.0 r22

Comment: Yep, this is an old version, which is unfortunately installed by default with XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a number of problems, it may be specific to a version of IE.  I tried it here on Vista/IE8 without getting a problem.

It could also be related to just your browser, locally; do you have any browser plug-ins installed that could be causing the problem? anything relating to web development & testing thats integrated into IE?  It could be related to Flash in some way, have you got the Flash development environment installed on your machine?  maybe theres a version mismatch there between the plug-in and the environment.

If you've got some javascript written into your web site also check this out, what you think looks like a crashing website might just be some busy javascript stuck in a loop.

Tracking down the problem requires lots of helpful people like me to check the website on their computers, to see if the problem is just you or more widespread ;-)

Comment: Thanks Phill. I've got IE8 with the developer toolbar installed natively, but it is also crashing IE6, 7, 8 in Microsoft's standard Virtual PC images. I don't develop in IE or flash, so I don't have any other tools installed.

It's reassuring at least that it's not happening to you!